# fetch the column values of a pandas data frame to a list

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

df:

```
Pattern     Count
 a           2
a,b          3
```

Expected Output:

```
  l1 = [['a'],['a','b']]
```

May be silly but new to pandas, so apologies.Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [`str.split`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.split.html) and [`tolist`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.tolist.html):

```
print df.Pattern.str.split(',').tolist()
[['a'], ['a', 'b']]
```